# Save GoogleApiClient on Activity restart in Bundle

Tags: android, serialization, parcelable, google-cast

My application has a function of theme change (i.e. Activity is restarting). Is it possible to save somehow `GoogleApiClient` with its all callbacks state and parameters into `Bundle` in `onSaveInstanceState()` so that I don't need to rebuild it every time?

I'm using Google Cast Api Client (for Chromecast devices).

```
                mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                    .addApi(Cast.API, apiOptionsBuilder.build())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mConnectionFailedListener)
                    .build();

            mApiClient.connect();
```

I found out that it is possible NOT to `disconnect()` this client. But still `mApiClient = null` after this.

I have also tried to put `mApiClient` as `savedInstanceState.putParcelable()` and `savedInstanceState.putSerializeble()` but this object isn't parcelable or serializible.

Full code of GoogleApiClient launcher:

```
 /**
 * Start the receiver app
 */
private void launchReceiver() {
    try {
        mCastListener = new Cast.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onApplicationDisconnected(int errorCode) {
                Log.d(TAG, "application has stopped");
                teardown();
            }

        };
        // Connect to Google Play services
        mConnectionCallbacks = new ConnectionCallbacks();
        mConnectionFailedListener = new ConnectionFailedListener();
        Cast.CastOptions.Builder apiOptionsBuilder = Cast.CastOptions
                .builder(mSelectedDevice, mCastListener);

        if (mApiClient == null) {
            mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                    .addApi(Cast.API, apiOptionsBuilder.build())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mConnectionFailedListener)
                    .build();

            mApiClient.connect();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed launchReceiver", e);
    }
}
```

It is not really user-friendly to reconnect to Chromecast device every time theme changed. Any solution for this?

Comment: You may extend application in a class and in that manage the state in its method.That will be created only once and just check that Bundle value saved and act accordingly!

Comment: @AndroidLearner I don't eally understand how that could work. Could you post an example as answer so I try that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should maintain the googleapiclient connection inside a **service rather that in an activity which can get killed during configuration changes**. Your theme change has no relation to apiclient object. So it is a good practice if you decouple your UI and core logic to avoid such issues.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting approach. I will try this out and let you know whether it worked.

Comment: If my answer helped you please post the update it may be helpful to others as well and also accept my answer.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Doing this for the first time :)

Comment: No worries just thought the same. Thank you:-) n happy my answer helped you.